# How to run a background service in android in PhoneGap app?

Tags: android, html, cordova, cross-platform, phonegap-plugins

Is there any PhoneGap plugin availabe to run a background service in android?

Comment: To be specific I am trying to create app which responds when there is an incoming call.So it has to run as a service i guess in background.

Comment: Check out this similar question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
I think you will have to go native for that functionality:
[Phonegap Background Service on iOS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841962/phonegap-background-service-on-ios4)