# Notification in Phonegap While App is not running

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I am working on an app with PhoneGap on android where the user will get messages every now and then bringing them to one of the pages on the app. I've looked at a few possibilities but haven't found any simple way to do this.  Can I use the built in Notification on the Phonegap API to do this?

I have found a few good ways to do push notifications like thisw:  http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-push-notification-for-phonegap/ but I want the notification to be coming from the app itself with the time determined by a built in timer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, not in Phonegap anyway. If the user leaves the app with the Home button, then the code is still running (until it gets killed when memory gets low). But if the user exists with the back key, the app dies. See here: [Creating an Android Service with Phonegap? (Have phonegap app run even when closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos)

Comment: so would it be reasonable to make a plugin that would do this?

Comment: Update: The latest phonegap-plugin-push support background notification