# build.phonegap.com - background process (task to complete at regular intervals whether app running or not)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using build.phonegap.com(for Android) , can I do some background operations like :
Lets assume that app is opened today, after that, it is opened only after 30days by the user. But, from today, every day some process should be done that updates the app whether the user opens it or not . So, can we employ this operation ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos

Comment: I am using build.phonegap.com which builds the apk.  I dont bother whether its a native code solution or something else. But I should be able to integrate it with build.phonegap.com

Comment: You should use a phonegap plugin. See: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService