# Service for Mobile Devices

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Past few days I have been working on couple of projects one was a Mobile application (created using Jquery mobile & Phonegap) and another was a Windows service.

I was wondering **is it possible to create a service for a mobile device using Jquery & Phonegap like technologies**. With a Service I mean a service like Windows Service which would be running in background, Will start itself on device boot etc.

```
If Yes then 
{
   HOW ? please share some resources and knowledge to chew on
}
If No then 
{
   what's the best way to develop a Mobile device service (platform dependent) ?
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an Android Service with Phonegap? (Have phonegap app run even when closed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to create device services using Jquery & Phonegap. Reason is you can't run Javascript code in the backend as a service. Phonegap simply renders the content inside a webview, so the Javascript code written is limited to that scope only.

> what's the best way to develop a Mobile device service (platform dependent) ?

Dive into native development.

Have a further read to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos), another discussion on SO.