# Need javascript to run as background plugin in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins

I have a javascript app that just sends text alerts with client specific info to the foreground every  specified time interval. For example, the user can set 4 specific messages to alert him/her every 2 hours). It's a pretty simple app. It uses the javascript setinterval command to time the alert presentation. I've studied several solutions that have been implemented along the lines of creating a background plugin so the app would still run when the home button is pressed and the alerts would happen, even when the app is not in the foreground. However, I'm still missing something critical to learning how to create and use these background services. How do I determine what part or parts of my javascript need to or should be executed in the plugin? For example, should the whole of my javascript be executed in the plugin, or just a portion of it and how do I know what plugin components will be required? Sorry, but I am obviously new to creating background plugins for phonegap. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check the first answer posted here [Creating an Android Service with Phonegap? (Have phonegap app run even when closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos) according to which it may not be possible