# Ionic App crashes when focus lost

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-timer

Im not sure if anyone else has experienced this, but the App I am building crashes on Android when it loses focus. Its a basic time recording App using angular-timer. I have handled it so when the app loads it checks to see if a timer was in progress and resumes, but I thought I would see if anyone else out there has seen this happen.

I can recreate the issue by opening the App, then opening Google Play while the app is running in the background. When I return to the Ionic App the splash screen is shown and the App loads from start again.

Comment: I don't think I need a service, I just didn't expect the app to close every time it lost focus. I guess it makes sense that all the javascript can only run in the one activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not "crashing", it's simply just not running in the background. See the many related questions here on StackOverflow:

- [Can phonegap app work in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211104/2714730)
- [Creating an Android service with Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos)
- [Background service plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService)