# Phonegap Build services in background

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

Is it possible to have a service running directly in an application even if it is not opened at the moment. Is this possible to do with PhonegapBuild and JS/Jquery/HTML only? Most of the information is based on using Java and androidManifest. but is there a solution for only web based languages? Are there any real plugins that can work?

I am using PushPlugin, but it has no information specified on how to send a notification in background.

Comment: Might still be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos

Answer (score 0):

Plugins for Phonegap will be moving to NPM. Here is your [search for background](http://plugins.cordova.io/npm/index.html?q=background). This link will find Plugins that offer background services.