# Cordova: Is there a way to keep a background service with cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web-applications, phonegap-plugins

I have written an app with cordova, while I want the app the fetch some data on a server, notify the user for new data, set an alarm for a specific time.

Is there a way or a plugin for me to do that?

I must support at least android and ios.

Comment: Maybe this post can help you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos

Comment: You could fork this [project](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) and implement further requirements or reimplement functionalities. It supports ios, android, wp 8.1

Comment: If you know that you should be using a plugin, then you should [search for a plugin](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=background)