# How to run background service in cordova/phonegap on device bootup?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I work on cordova cross platform. I want to start background service on device boot:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
     myService = cordova.plugins.myService;
     upload();
},
true);
```

Comment: As per your code, service will start only when your app is opened otherwise service won't start.

Comment: then how i start my service when device is bootup please help me

Comment: If you make it `sticky` then it will start whenever device is rebooted but initially on installation of app for first tie you will have to open app once so that service will start first time.

Comment: if you have any sample code for the same please share with me

Comment: please help me i am new in phonegap

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos   2. https://github.com/Red-Folder/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BackgroundService