# created services for data synchronization in ionic 2 (even when the application closes)

Tags: android, ios, service, synchronization, ionic2

I'm writing a program that uses ionic 2.

I want users to be able to CRUD when offline, the online data is synchronized with the server itself, even if the program shuts down,

I've tried using cordova-plugin-background-mode, but not when the program off the code does not work.

I think one can write native Android app to create service can sync data when online, offline (impact data into the same file as sql lite)

People can give me solution, sorry for my expression is not good

Comment: What is the question? You can use local storage for temporary storing of daga, and you can use sqlite for storing data in the phones database.

Comment: From what I understand you want to create a service to sync data when the application is completely closed.  You probably have to create your own service check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343828/creating-an-android-service-with-phonegap-have-phonegap-app-run-even-when-clos

Comment: Maybe [this (amazing) post](https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/) from Josh Morony could be helpful.

Comment: @kumaro thank you, here is the answer I was looking for , I will learn more, thank all